# Why is move_and_slide() not working in Godot?

Tags: godot, gdscript

In Godot engine version 3.4, move_and_slide isn't working.

```
extends KinematicBody2D

var velocity = Vector2(0,0)

func _process(delta):
    velocity.x = (Input.get_action_strength("right")-Input.get_action_strength("left"))*100
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity,Vector2.UP)
```

When I run this code, the KinematicBody2D doesn't move. Does anyone know why?

Comment: You have several typos: `veloctiy` vs `veolicty` vs `velocity`.

Comment: I fixed the typos.

Comment: If that is not the issue, then check the input map for the actions "right" and "left" in your project settings.

Comment: The input map is not the issue either. Velocity changes correctly when I press left or right.

Comment: Oh, would it be moving too slow? `Velocity.x` is at most 100. In 2D that means 100 pixels per second. Which is a little over a pixel per frame at 60hz. Well, that or there is something else stopping it.

Comment: I increased the multiplier and it works. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

The Answer is inside the Comment.

> Blockquote I increased the multiplier and it works. Thank you so much. > Blockquote

The Velocity Multiplier is too low

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
extends KinematicBody2D


var velocity = Vector2.ZERO
var speed = 20000
func _physics_process(delta):
    var input_velocity = Vector2.ZERO

    input_velocity.x = Input.get_action_strength("ui_right")-Input.get_action_strength("ui_left")
    input_velocity.y = Input.get_action_strength("ui_down")-Input.get_action_strength("ui_up")

    velocity.x = (input_velocity.x)*speed*delta
    velocity.y = (input_velocity.y)*speed*delta

    move_and_slide(velocity)
```